# why does carriage return \r autoflush print function output?

Tags: python-3.x

I understand that normally the print function default end parameter is "\n":

```
print("test", end='\n')
```

so I have two examples that will explain the idea:

```py
for i in range (1,5):
    print(i,end='test')
    time.sleep(1)
```

in this code the print statement won't print any values until all the waiting is done, as the output will be buffered.

Then why here

```py
for i in range (1,5):
    print(i,end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

the output is flushed automatically? I understand that there is a parameter called `flush` that can control it, but why does carriage return (`\r`) auto flush the output?

I understand that `\n` and when execution is done the buffer is flushed, but why does `\r` also flush the buffer. Are there any other cases where `end` parameter values might affect that?

I tried searching on it in python docs but haven't found any helpful information.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) inquiry: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkusSafar not really XY: the question is not "how can I do X" at all. It's asking about language behaviour - no matter how and if it can be applied. Would you call "How is diamond inheritance problem solved in python" XY-ish, if OP is not solving any actual problem?

Comment: \r is a special case because traditionally it is part of the `\r\n` terminal line termination sequence. How \r works on any given terminal varies (and may be configurable). Sometimes its converted to a \n in the terminal pipeline for instance. I'm not surprised that clib is flushing it.

Comment: I think Python doesn't control that. It just tell the C standard library to use line buffering. So, in which operating system are you working? In any case, you can use `-u` option in python or an env variable to have stdout unbuffered. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout Else: I think you can reopen stdout with your line buffering

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike I agree, I just wanted to dive a little bit into the possibility that it might be something of that kind (and should have formulated it that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `stdout` is often line buffered, if it is attached to a terminal.

But also `stdout` is opened as text, so with *universal newlines* (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines). Note: it is not dependent on OS, it just allow all possible ways. The page https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper is more explicit: `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n` are all interpreted as new line, on all operating systems.